# Why isn't $S^2$ a lie group?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, lie-groups

Why isn't $S^2$ a lie group? The only spheres that are Lie groups are $S^0$,$S^1$ and $S^3$. What about these spheres makes them special so that they are the only spheres that can be given a continuous group structure?

Comment: On the 2-sphere, what group operation would you put ? On the circle, it's induced by complex multiplication, and on the 3-sphere, by quaternionic multiplication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lie group is a parallelizable manifold, in particular there exists a vector field which does not vanish. This implies that the Euler characteristic is zero. The Euler characteristic of the sphere is $2$

Comment: Also see "hairy ball theorem".

Comment: Incidentally [much more is true](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/adams1.pdf) (and in fact [even more than that](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm164/fm16431.pdf)), but that takes a lot more work.

Comment: Since this question was closed as a duplicate, and the older question has only a wrong answer, this answer should be moved there.